# Triple ampersand in Sass

Tags: javascript, css, sass, styled-components

What does three ampersands do in Sass?

Here in a `styled-components` context:

```
const Grid = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  &&& {
    ${someFunction}
  }
`
```

Seen in code here:
https://github.com/reakit/reakit/blob/website%400.16.0/packages/reakit/src/Grid/Grid.ts#L23

Comment: it's & parent selector repeating three times, no reason

Comment: @VadimHulevich I'm not sure I'm following. Mind writing up an answer?

Comment: I'm not sure it's valid sass. I just tried to run that, and got the following error: 
`"&" may only used at the beginning of a compound selector.`. Maybe that repo has got some custom compile options specified somewhere, just looking now...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [docs](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/faqs#how-can-i-override-styles-with-higher-specificity) say it is to override any already given styles with a higher specificity, as an alternative to using `!important`.

It affects the generated css classes.

Comment: I would add that it generate the selector the number of times the ampersand is used (three in this case) giving a CSS specificity of 3 classes (or tag). Not as strong as important or an id, but strong enough for most CSS methodologies.

Comment: It is not technically an alternative to `!important`. Things will get uglier if used `!important` everywhere instead of increasing the specificity.